# Razer Ouroboros mouse not working

Tags: xorg, gentoo, mouse

## The Problem

I don't mean the extra keys and what not, I'm just talking about getting the pointer to move across the screen and the left and right buttons to click.

I've got it plugged into the system directly using the cable.

I'm running Gentoo right now. The mouse works fine in the Ubuntu live CD on the same machine.

I got it working on another Gentoo installation. That installation has three major differences:

1. It is slightly more up to date.
2. I was using a USB3 port, instead of a USB2 port.
3. It's using a genkernel kernel, instead of a custom one. I've been unable to test genkernel on this machine because genkernel is apparently unable to generate a kernel that boots on this one.

Next thing I can try is to update my installation.

I also need to try this on something like Ubuntu to see if it can autodetect the hardware, because that will confirm that my problem is related to configuration.

So does anyone have any ideas? I couldn't find **anything** about this mouse on Linux on the Internet. I've also never seen a mouse flat-out not working on Linux.

Here's the relevant output I could find:

```
cat /dev/input/event9
ÂµS°cat: /dev/input/event9: No such device
cat: /dev/input/event9: No such device
```

*In this case `event9` is the device assigned to the mouse, see `Xorg.0.log` below.*
The characters before the error messages are random, which make me think they are mouse movements. They also pop up after some time.

The mouse appears to disconnect / reconnect whenever I press one of the mouse buttons:

```
Jul  7 23:09:33 straylight kernel: usb 2-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 10
Jul  7 23:09:34 straylight kernel: usb 2-1.2: new full-speed USB device number 11 using ehci-pci
Jul  7 23:09:34 straylight kernel: usb 2-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=1532, idProduct=0032
Jul  7 23:09:34 straylight kernel: usb 2-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
Jul  7 23:09:34 straylight kernel: usb 2-1.2: Product: Razer Ouroboros
Jul  7 23:09:34 straylight kernel: usb 2-1.2: Manufacturer: Razer
Jul  7 23:09:34 straylight kernel: input: Razer Razer Ouroboros as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/input/input31
Jul  7 23:09:34 straylight kernel: hid-generic 0003:1532:0032.001D: input,hidraw4: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Razer Razer Ouroboros] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.2/input0
Jul  7 23:09:34 straylight kernel: input: Razer Razer Ouroboros as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.1/input/input32
Jul  7 23:09:34 straylight kernel: hid-generic 0003:1532:0032.001E: input,hidraw5: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Razer Razer Ouroboros] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.2/input1
Jul  7 23:09:34 straylight kernel: input: Razer Razer Ouroboros as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.2/input/input33
Jul  7 23:09:34 straylight kernel: hid-generic 0003:1532:0032.001F: input,hidraw6: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Razer Razer Ouroboros] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.2/input2
```

## Things I've Tried

- I re-compiled my kernel with CONFIG_USB_EHCI_TT_NEWSCHED=y, since some people suggested that. It had no effect as far as I could tell.
- I upgraded my kernel to the newest version that was available, no change.
- I tried the kernel config from the other Gentoo machine, no change.

## Currently Investigating

- I suspect there's some sort of issue with USB2 vs USB3. The other machine has a USB3 port, and the problematic one doesn't. I've also experienced problems with this regarding MTP.

## Assorted Logs

**dmesg**

```
[  731.127793] hub 1-1:1.0: debounce: port 6: total 100ms stable 100ms status 0x101
[  731.138749] hub 1-1:1.0: port 6 not reset yet, waiting 10ms
[  731.200606] usb 1-1.6: new full-speed USB device number 11 using ehci_hcd
[  731.211559] hub 1-1:1.0: port 6 not reset yet, waiting 10ms
[  731.287115] usb 1-1.6: skipped 1 descriptor after interface
[  731.287122] usb 1-1.6: skipped 1 descriptor after interface
[  731.287126] usb 1-1.6: skipped 1 descriptor after interface
[  731.287478] usb 1-1.6: default language 0x0409
[  731.287967] usb 1-1.6: udev 11, busnum 1, minor = 10
[  731.287969] usb 1-1.6: New USB device found, idVendor=1532, idProduct=0032
[  731.287971] usb 1-1.6: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[  731.287973] usb 1-1.6: Product: Razer Ouroboros                                                                    
[  731.287974] usb 1-1.6: Manufacturer: Razer
[  731.288020] usb 1-1.6: usb_probe_device
[  731.288023] usb 1-1.6: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
[  731.288482] usb 1-1.6: adding 1-1.6:1.0 (config #1, interface 0)
[  731.288511] usbhid 1-1.6:1.0: usb_probe_interface
[  731.288513] usbhid 1-1.6:1.0: usb_probe_interface - got id
[  731.289236] input: Razer Razer Ouroboros as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.6/1-1.6:1.0/input/input32
[  731.289292] hid-generic 0003:1532:0032.001A: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Razer Razer Ouroboros] on usb-0000:
00:1a.0-1.6/input0
[  731.289303] usb 1-1.6: adding 1-1.6:1.1 (config #1, interface 1)
[  731.289324] usbhid 1-1.6:1.1: usb_probe_interface
[  731.289326] usbhid 1-1.6:1.1: usb_probe_interface - got id
[  731.291438] input: Razer Razer Ouroboros as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.6/1-1.6:1.1/input/input33
[  731.291467] usb 1-1.6: link qh1-0601/ffff880129a56100 start 0 [1/2 us]
[  731.291512] hid-generic 0003:1532:0032.001B: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Razer Razer Ouroboros] on usb-00
00:00:1a.0-1.6/input1
[  731.291522] usb 1-1.6: adding 1-1.6:1.2 (config #1, interface 2)
[  731.291542] usbhid 1-1.6:1.2: usb_probe_interface
[  731.291544] usbhid 1-1.6:1.2: usb_probe_interface - got id
[  731.292411] input: Razer Razer Ouroboros as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.6/1-1.6:1.2/input/input34
[  731.292518] usb 1-1.6: link qh1-3008/ffff880129a56800 start 0 [1/2 us]
[  731.292567] hid-generic 0003:1532:0032.001C: input,hidraw3: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Razer Razer Ouroboros] on usb-00
00:00:1a.0-1.6/input2
[  731.292582] hub 1-1:1.0: state 7 ports 6 chg 0000 evt 0040
[  731.302537] joydev: version magic '3.6.11-ck SMP mod_unload modversions ' should be '3.6.11-ck SMP preempt mod_unloa
d '
[  731.302576] joydev: version magic '3.6.11-ck SMP mod_unload modversions ' should be '3.6.11-ck SMP preempt mod_unloa
d '
[  731.302606] joydev: version magic '3.6.11-ck SMP mod_unload modversions ' should be '3.6.11-ck SMP preempt mod_unloa
d '
```

**/var/log/messages**

```
    Jul  3 22:42:11 straylight kernel: [  712.192976] usb 1-1.6: unlink qh1-3008/ffff880129abc000 start 0 [1/2 us]
    Jul  3 22:42:11 straylight kernel: [  712.193600] usb 1-1.6: unlink qh1-0601/ffff880129abcc80 start 0 [1/2 us]
    Jul  3 22:42:11 straylight kernel: [  712.205991] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1a.0: reused qh ffff880129abc000 schedule
    Jul  3 22:42:11 straylight kernel: [  712.205999] usb 1-1.6: link qh1-3008/ffff880129abc000 start 0 [1/2 us]
    Jul  3 22:42:11 straylight kernel: [  712.206071] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1a.0: reused qh ffff880129abcc80 schedule
    Jul  3 22:42:11 straylight kernel: [  712.206073] usb 1-1.6: link qh1-0601/ffff880129abcc80 start 0 [1/2 us]
    Jul  3 22:42:11 straylight kernel: [  712.208558] usb 1-1.6: unlink qh1-0601/ffff880129abcc80 start 0 [1/2 us]
    Jul  3 22:42:11 straylight kernel: [  712.208846] usb 1-1.6: unlink qh1-3008/ffff880129abc000 start 0 [1/2 us]
    Jul  3 22:42:11 straylight kernel: [  712.233918] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1a.0: reused qh ffff880129abcc80 schedule
    Jul  3 22:42:11 straylight kernel: [  712.233925] usb 1-1.6: link qh1-0601/ffff880129abcc80 start 0 [1/2 us]
    Jul  3 22:42:11 straylight kernel: [  712.234942] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1a.0: reused qh ffff880129abc000 schedule
    Jul  3 22:42:11 straylight kernel: [  712.234950] usb 1-1.6: link qh1-3008/ffff880129abc000 start 0 [1/2 us]
    Jul  3 22:42:11 straylight kernel: [  712.236489] usb 1-1.6: unlink qh1-0601/ffff880129abcc80 start 0 [1/2 us]
    Jul  3 22:42:11 straylight kernel: [  712.237862] usb 1-1.6: unlink qh1-3008/ffff880129abc000 start 0 [1/2 us]
    Jul  3 22:42:11 straylight kernel: [  712.287776] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1a.0: reused qh ffff880129abcc80 schedule
    Jul  3 22:42:11 straylight kernel: [  712.287783] usb 1-1.6: link qh1-0601/ffff880129abcc80 start 0 [1/2 us]
    Jul  3 22:42:11 straylight kernel: [  712.289711] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1a.0: reused qh ffff880129abc000 schedule
    Jul  3 22:42:11 straylight kernel: [  712.289714] usb 1-1.6: link qh1-3008/ffff880129abc000 start 0 [1/2 us]
    Jul  3 22:42:11 straylight kernel: [  712.290350] usb 1-1.6: unlink qh1-0601/ffff880129abcc80 start 0 [1/2 us]
    Jul  3 22:42:11 straylight kernel: [  712.292682] usb 1-1.6: unlink qh1-3008/ffff880129abc000 start 0 [1/2 us]
    Jul  3 22:42:11 straylight kernel: [  712.326145] hub 1-1:1.0: state 7 ports 6 chg 0000 evt 0040
    Jul  3 22:42:11 straylight kernel: [  712.326411] hub 1-1:1.0: port 6, status 0100, change 0001, 12 Mb/s
    Jul  3 22:42:11 straylight kernel: [  712.326549] usb 1-1.6: USB disconnect, device number 9
    Jul  3 22:42:11 straylight kernel: [  712.326553] usb 1-1.6: unregistering device
    Jul  3 22:42:11 straylight kernel: [  712.326556] usb 1-1.6: unregistering interface 1-1.6:1.0
    Jul  3 22:42:11 straylight kernel: [  712.340765] usb 1-1.6: unregistering interface 1-1.6:1.1
    Jul  3 22:42:11 straylight kernel: [  712.363711] usb 1-1.6: unregistering interface 1-1.6:1.2
    Jul  3 22:42:11 straylight kernel: [  712.386641] usb 1-1.6: usb_disable_device nuking all URBs
    Jul  3 22:42:11 straylight kernel: [  712.490532] hub 1-1:1.0: debounce: port 6: total 100ms stable 100ms status 0x100
    Jul  3 22:42:23 straylight kernel: [  724.582656] hub 1-1:1.0: state 7 ports 6 chg 0000 evt 0040
    Jul  3 22:42:23 straylight kernel: [  724.583140] hub 1-1:1.0: port 6, status 0101, change 0001, 12 Mb/s
    Jul  3 22:42:23 straylight kernel: [  724.686611] hub 1-1:1.0: debounce: port 6: total 100ms stable 100ms status 0x101
    Jul  3 22:42:23 straylight kernel: [  724.697599] hub 1-1:1.0: port 6 not reset yet, waiting 10ms
    Jul  3 22:42:23 straylight kernel: [  724.759421] usb 1-1.6: new full-speed USB device number 10 using ehci_hcd
    Jul  3 22:42:23 straylight kernel: [  724.770414] hub 1-1:1.0: port 6 not reset yet, waiting 10ms
    Jul  3 22:42:23 straylight kernel: [  724.846327] usb 1-1.6: skipped 1 descriptor after interface
    Jul  3 22:42:23 straylight kernel: [  724.846334] usb 1-1.6: skipped 1 descriptor after interface
    Jul  3 22:42:23 straylight kernel: [  724.846338] usb 1-1.6: skipped 1 descriptor after interface
    Jul  3 22:42:23 straylight kernel: [  724.846601] usb 1-1.6: default language 0x0409
    Jul  3 22:42:23 straylight kernel: [  724.847101] usb 1-1.6: udev 10, busnum 1, minor = 9
    Jul  3 22:42:23 straylight kernel: [  724.847108] usb 1-1.6: New USB device found, idVendor=1532, idProduct=0032
    Jul  3 22:42:23 straylight kernel: [  724.847112] usb 1-1.6: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
    Jul  3 22:42:23 straylight kernel: [  724.847115] usb 1-1.6: Product: Razer Ouroboros
    Jul  3 22:42:23 straylight kernel: [  724.847119] usb 1-1.6: Manufacturer: Razer
    Jul  3 22:42:23 straylight kernel: [  724.847220] usb 1-1.6: usb_probe_device
    Jul  3 22:42:23 straylight kernel: [  724.847225] usb 1-1.6: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
    Jul  3 22:42:23 straylight kernel: [  724.847437] usb 1-1.6: adding 1-1.6:1.0 (config #1, interface 0)
    Jul  3 22:42:23 straylight kernel: [  724.847467] usbhid 1-1.6:1.0: usb_probe_interface
    Jul  3 22:42:23 straylight kernel: [  724.847469] usbhid 1-1.6:1.0: usb_probe_interface - got id
    Jul  3 22:42:23 straylight kernel: [  724.848170] input: Razer Razer Ouroboros as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.6/1-1.6:1.0/input/input29
    Jul  3 22:42:23 straylight kernel: [  724.848230] hid-generic 0003:1532:0032.0017: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Razer Razer Ouroboros] on usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.6/input0
    Jul  3 22:42:23 straylight kernel: [  724.848240] usb 1-1.6: adding 1-1.6:1.1 (config #1, interface 1)
    Jul  3 22:42:23 straylight kernel: [  724.848261] usbhid 1-1.6:1.1: usb_probe_interface
    Jul  3 22:42:23 straylight kernel: [  724.848263] usbhid 1-1.6:1.1: usb_probe_interface - got id
    Jul  3 22:42:23 straylight kernel: [  724.850516] input: Razer Razer Ouroboros as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.6/1-1.6:1.1/input/input30
    Jul  3 22:42:23 straylight kernel: [  724.850550] usb 1-1.6: link qh1-0601/ffff880129a56e00 start 0 [1/2 us]
    Jul  3 22:42:23 straylight kernel: [  724.850594] hid-generic 0003:1532:0032.0018: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Razer Razer Ouroboros] on usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.6/input1
    Jul  3 22:42:23 straylight kernel: [  724.850604] usb 1-1.6: adding 1-1.6:1.2 (config #1, interface 2)
    Jul  3 22:42:23 straylight kernel: [  724.850625] usbhid 1-1.6:1.2: usb_probe_interface
    Jul  3 22:42:23 straylight kernel: [  724.850627] usbhid 1-1.6:1.2: usb_probe_interface - got id
    Jul  3 22:42:23 straylight kernel: [  724.851371] input: Razer Razer Ouroboros as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.6/1-1.6:1.2/input/input31
    Jul  3 22:42:23 straylight kernel: [  724.851444] usb 1-1.6: link qh1-3008/ffff880129a56f80 start 0 [1/2 us]
    Jul  3 22:42:23 straylight kernel: [  724.851507] hid-generic 0003:1532:0032.0019: input,hidraw3: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Razer Razer Ouroboros] on usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.6/input2
    Jul  3 22:42:23 straylight mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 10: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.6"
    Jul  3 22:42:23 straylight mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 10 was not an MTP device
    Jul  3 22:42:24 straylight kernel: [  724.862885] joydev: version magic '3.6.11-ck SMP mod_unload modversions ' should be '3.6.11-ck SMP preempt mod_unload '
    Jul  3 22:42:24 straylight kernel: [  724.862928] joydev: version magic '3.6.11-ck SMP mod_unload modversions ' should be '3.6.11-ck SMP preempt mod_unload '
    Jul  3 22:42:24 straylight kernel: [  724.862961] joydev: version magic '3.6.11-ck SMP mod_unload modversions ' should be '3.6.11-ck SMP preempt mod_unload '
    Jul  3 22:42:29 straylight kernel: [  730.821629] usb 1-1.6: unlink qh1-0601/ffff880129a56e00 start 0 [1/2 us]
    Jul  3 22:42:29 straylight kernel: [  730.821913] usb 1-1.6: unlink qh1-3008/ffff880129a56f80 start 0 [1/2 us]
    Jul  3 22:42:29 straylight kernel: [  730.834277] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1a.0: reused qh ffff880129a56e00 schedule
    Jul  3 22:42:29 straylight kernel: [  730.834285] usb 1-1.6: link qh1-0601/ffff880129a56e00 start 0 [1/2 us]
    Jul  3 22:42:29 straylight kernel: [  730.834361] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1a.0: reused qh ffff880129a56f80 schedule
    Jul  3 22:42:29 straylight kernel: [  730.834363] usb 1-1.6: link qh1-3008/ffff880129a56f80 start 0 [1/2 us]
    Jul  3 22:42:29 straylight kernel: [  730.836957] usb 1-1.6: unlink qh1-3008/ffff880129a56f80 start 0 [1/2 us]
    Jul  3 22:42:29 straylight kernel: [  730.837546] usb 1-1.6: unlink qh1-0601/ffff880129a56e00 start 0 [1/2 us]
    Jul  3 22:42:30 straylight kernel: [  730.862205] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1a.0: reused qh ffff880129a56f80 schedule
    Jul  3 22:42:30 straylight kernel: [  730.862212] usb 1-1.6: link qh1-3008/ffff880129a56f80 start 0 [1/2 us]
    Jul  3 22:42:30 straylight kernel: [  730.863232] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1a.0: reused qh ffff880129a56e00 schedule
    Jul  3 22:42:30 straylight kernel: [  730.863240] usb 1-1.6: link qh1-0601/ffff880129a56e00 start 0 [1/2 us]
    Jul  3 22:42:30 straylight kernel: [  730.864890] usb 1-1.6: unlink qh1-3008/ffff880129a56f80 start 0 [1/2 us]
    Jul  3 22:42:30 straylight kernel: [  730.866510] usb 1-1.6: unlink qh1-0601/ffff880129a56e00 start 0 [1/2 us]
    Jul  3 22:42:30 straylight kernel: [  730.916066] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1a.0: reused qh ffff880129a56f80 schedule
    Jul  3 22:42:30 straylight kernel: [  730.916074] usb 1-1.6: link qh1-3008/ffff880129a56f80 start 0 [1/2 us]
    Jul  3 22:42:30 straylight kernel: [  730.918081] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1a.0: reused qh ffff880129a56e00 schedule
    Jul  3 22:42:30 straylight kernel: [  730.918089] usb 1-1.6: link qh1-0601/ffff880129a56e00 start 0 [1/2 us]
    Jul  3 22:42:30 straylight kernel: [  730.918750] usb 1-1.6: unlink qh1-3008/ffff880129a56f80 start 0 [1/2 us]
    Jul  3 22:42:30 straylight kernel: [  730.921368] usb 1-1.6: unlink qh1-0601/ffff880129a56e00 start 0 [1/2 us]
    Jul  3 22:42:30 straylight kernel: [  730.966209] hub 1-1:1.0: state 7 ports 6 chg 0000 evt 0040
    Jul  3 22:42:30 straylight kernel: [  730.966467] hub 1-1:1.0: port 6, status 0101, change 0001, 12 Mb/s
    Jul  3 22:42:30 straylight kernel: [  730.966579] usb 1-1.6: USB disconnect, device number 10
    Jul  3 22:42:30 straylight kernel: [  730.966581] usb 1-1.6: unregistering device
    Jul  3 22:42:30 straylight kernel: [  730.966583] usb 1-1.6: unregistering interface 1-1.6:1.0
    Jul  3 22:42:30 straylight kernel: [  730.979027] usb 1-1.6: unregistering interface 1-1.6:1.1
    Jul  3 22:42:30 straylight kernel: [  730.997019] usb 1-1.6: unregistering interface 1-1.6:1.2
    Jul  3 22:42:30 straylight kernel: [  731.023909] usb 1-1.6: usb_disable_device nuking all URBs
    Jul  3 22:42:30 straylight kernel: [  731.127793] hub 1-1:1.0: debounce: port 6: total 100ms stable 100ms status 0x101
    Jul  3 22:42:30 straylight kernel: [  731.138749] hub 1-1:1.0: port 6 not reset yet, waiting 10ms
    Jul  3 22:42:30 straylight kernel: [  731.200606] usb 1-1.6: new full-speed USB device number 11 using ehci_hcd
    Jul  3 22:42:30 straylight kernel: [  731.211559] hub 1-1:1.0: port 6 not reset yet, waiting 10ms
    Jul  3 22:42:30 straylight kernel: [  731.287115] usb 1-1.6: skipped 1 descriptor after interface
    Jul  3 22:42:30 straylight kernel: [  731.287122] usb 1-1.6: skipped 1 descriptor after interface
    Jul  3 22:42:30 straylight kernel: [  731.287126] usb 1-1.6: skipped 1 descriptor after interface
    Jul  3 22:42:30 straylight kernel: [  731.287478] usb 1-1.6: default language 0x0409
    Jul  3 22:42:30 straylight kernel: [  731.287967] usb 1-1.6: udev 11, busnum 1, minor = 10
    Jul  3 22:42:30 straylight kernel: [  731.287969] usb 1-1.6: New USB device found, idVendor=1532, idProduct=0032
    Jul  3 22:42:30 straylight kernel: [  731.287971] usb 1-1.6: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
    Jul  3 22:42:30 straylight kernel: [  731.287973] usb 1-1.6: Product: Razer Ouroboros
    Jul  3 22:42:30 straylight kernel: [  731.287974] usb 1-1.6: Manufacturer: Razer
    Jul  3 22:42:30 straylight kernel: [  731.288020] usb 1-1.6: usb_probe_device
    Jul  3 22:42:30 straylight kernel: [  731.288023] usb 1-1.6: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
    Jul  3 22:42:30 straylight kernel: [  731.288482] usb 1-1.6: adding 1-1.6:1.0 (config #1, interface 0)
    Jul  3 22:42:30 straylight kernel: [  731.288511] usbhid 1-1.6:1.0: usb_probe_interface
    Jul  3 22:42:30 straylight kernel: [  731.288513] usbhid 1-1.6:1.0: usb_probe_interface - got id
    Jul  3 22:42:30 straylight kernel: [  731.289236] input: Razer Razer Ouroboros as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.6/1-1.6:1.0/input/input32
    Jul  3 22:42:30 straylight kernel: [  731.289292] hid-generic 0003:1532:0032.001A: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Razer Razer Ouroboros] on usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.6/input0
    Jul  3 22:42:30 straylight kernel: [  731.289303] usb 1-1.6: adding 1-1.6:1.1 (config #1, interface 1)
    Jul  3 22:42:30 straylight kernel: [  731.289324] usbhid 1-1.6:1.1: usb_probe_interface
    Jul  3 22:42:30 straylight kernel: [  731.289326] usbhid 1-1.6:1.1: usb_probe_interface - got id
    Jul  3 22:42:30 straylight kernel: [  731.291438] input: Razer Razer Ouroboros as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.6/1-1.6:1.1/input/input33
    Jul  3 22:42:30 straylight kernel: [  731.291467] usb 1-1.6: link qh1-0601/ffff880129a56100 start 0 [1/2 us]
    Jul  3 22:42:30 straylight kernel: [  731.291512] hid-generic 0003:1532:0032.001B: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Razer Razer Ouroboros] on usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.6/input1
    Jul  3 22:42:30 straylight kernel: [  731.291522] usb 1-1.6: adding 1-1.6:1.2 (config #1, interface 2)
    Jul  3 22:42:30 straylight kernel: [  731.291542] usbhid 1-1.6:1.2: usb_probe_interface
    Jul  3 22:42:30 straylight kernel: [  731.291544] usbhid 1-1.6:1.2: usb_probe_interface - got id
    Jul  3 22:42:30 straylight kernel: [  731.292411] input: Razer Razer Ouroboros as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.6/1-1.6:1.2/input/input34
    Jul  3 22:42:30 straylight kernel: [  731.292518] usb 1-1.6: link qh1-3008/ffff880129a56800 start 0 [1/2 us]
    Jul  3 22:42:30 straylight kernel: [  731.292567] hid-generic 0003:1532:0032.001C: input,hidraw3: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Razer Razer Ouroboros] on usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.6/input2
    Jul  3 22:42:30 straylight kernel: [  731.292582] hub 1-1:1.0: state 7 ports 6 chg 0000 evt 0040
    Jul  3 22:42:30 straylight mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 11: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.6"
    Jul  3 22:42:30 straylight mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 11 was not an MTP device
    Jul  3 22:42:30 straylight kernel: [  731.302537] joydev: version magic '3.6.11-ck SMP mod_unload modversions ' should be '3.6.11-ck SMP preempt mod_unload '
    Jul  3 22:42:30 straylight kernel: [  731.302576] joydev: version magic '3.6.11-ck SMP mod_unload modversions ' should be '3.6.11-ck SMP preempt mod_unload '
    Jul  3 22:42:30 straylight kernel: [  731.302606] joydev: version magic '3.6.11-ck SMP mod_unload modversions ' should be '3.6.11-ck SMP preempt mod_unload '
```

**/var/log/Xorg.0.log**

```
[   732.888] (II) config/udev: removing device Razer Razer Ouroboros
[   732.899] (II) evdev: Razer Razer Ouroboros: Close
[   732.899] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
[   732.911] (II) config/udev: removing device Razer Razer Ouroboros
[   732.920] (II) evdev: Razer Razer Ouroboros: Close
[   732.920] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
[   733.201] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Razer Razer Ouroboros (/dev/input/event8)
[   733.201] (**) Razer Razer Ouroboros: Applying InputClass "evdev pointer catchall"
[   733.201] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Razer Razer Ouroboros'
[   733.201] (**) Razer Razer Ouroboros: always reports core events
[   733.201] (**) evdev: Razer Razer Ouroboros: Device: "/dev/input/event8"
[   733.214] (EE) evdev: Razer Razer Ouroboros: Unable to open evdev device "/dev/input/event8".
[   733.214] (EE) PreInit returned 2 for "Razer Razer Ouroboros"
[   733.214] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
[   733.214] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Razer Razer Ouroboros (/dev/input/mouse1)
[   733.214] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   733.214] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   733.214] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Razer Razer Ouroboros (/dev/input/event10)
[   733.214] (**) Razer Razer Ouroboros: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[   733.214] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Razer Razer Ouroboros'
[   733.214] (**) Razer Razer Ouroboros: always reports core events
[   733.214] (**) evdev: Razer Razer Ouroboros: Device: "/dev/input/event10"
[   733.214] (--) evdev: Razer Razer Ouroboros: Vendor 0x1532 Product 0x32
[   733.214] (--) evdev: Razer Razer Ouroboros: Found keys
[   733.214] (II) evdev: Razer Razer Ouroboros: Configuring as keyboard
[   733.214] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.6/1-1.6:1.2/input/input34/event10"
[   733.214] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Razer Razer Ouroboros" (type: KEYBOARD, id 8)
[   733.214] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[   733.214] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc104"
[   733.214] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[   733.215] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Razer Razer Ouroboros (/dev/input/event9)
[   733.215] (**) Razer Razer Ouroboros: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[   733.215] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Razer Razer Ouroboros'
[   733.215] (**) Razer Razer Ouroboros: always reports core events
[   733.215] (**) evdev: Razer Razer Ouroboros: Device: "/dev/input/event9"
[   733.215] (II) evdev: Razer Razer Ouroboros: Using mtdev for this device
[   733.215] (--) evdev: Razer Razer Ouroboros: Vendor 0x1532 Product 0x32
[   733.215] (--) evdev: Razer Razer Ouroboros: Found 1 mouse buttons
[   733.215] (--) evdev: Razer Razer Ouroboros: Found scroll wheel(s)
[   733.215] (--) evdev: Razer Razer Ouroboros: Found relative axes
[   733.215] (II) evdev: Razer Razer Ouroboros: Forcing relative x/y axes to exist.
[   733.215] (--) evdev: Razer Razer Ouroboros: Found absolute axes
[   733.215] (--) evdev: Razer Razer Ouroboros: Found absolute multitouch axes
[   733.215] (--) evdev: Razer Razer Ouroboros: Found keys
[   733.215] (II) evdev: Razer Razer Ouroboros: Configuring as mouse
[   733.215] (II) evdev: Razer Razer Ouroboros: Configuring as keyboard
[   733.215] (II) evdev: Razer Razer Ouroboros: Adding scrollwheel support
[   733.215] (**) evdev: Razer Razer Ouroboros: YAxisMapping: buttons 4 and 5
[   733.215] (**) evdev: Razer Razer Ouroboros: EmulateWheelButton: 4, EmulateWheelInertia: 10, EmulateWheelTimeout: 200
[   733.215] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.6/1-1.6:1.1/input/input33/event9"
[   733.215] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Razer Razer Ouroboros" (type: KEYBOARD, id 9)
[   733.215] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[   733.215] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc104"
[   733.215] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[   733.215] (II) evdev: Razer Razer Ouroboros: initialized for relative axes.
[   733.215] (WW) evdev: Razer Razer Ouroboros: ignoring absolute axes.
[   733.215] (**) Razer Razer Ouroboros: (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1
[   733.215] (**) Razer Razer Ouroboros: (accel) acceleration profile 0
[   733.215] (**) Razer Razer Ouroboros: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[   733.215] (**) Razer Razer Ouroboros: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
```

Comment: I think this mouse has embedded DRM and usually requires activation?? I've never seen something like that. There is allusion to this in the requirements from the tech spec of the [mouse](http://www.razerzone.com/gaming-mice/razer-ouroboros). It is not your everyday mouse that's for sure.

Comment: No DRM that I'm aware of. There was no DRM on the Windows side in any case, and I installed it on the other Gentoo system first.

Comment: In any case, I got it working now (see below), but it sure isn't your run-of-the-mill mouse!

Comment: From the link: "Razer Synapse 2.0 registration (requiring a valid e-mail), software download, license acceptance, and internet connection needed to activate full features of product and for software updates. After activation, full features are available in optional offline mode." Don't know if it's related. Maybe shouldn't impact the base features but who knows how they implemented that and how non-Windows OS deals with that. Happy you got it working!

Comment: I don't even have it installed on Windows ;) I think it's for things like setting the colour of the lights and what not.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it has something to do with USB2 / USB3 issues on Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue on my Clevo W110ER running Gentoo 4.0.9. Ouroboros worked well on both USB3.0 ports but not on USB2.0 port (though dmesg showed it was attached).
Setting

```
CONFIG_USB_EHCI_ROOT_HUB_TT=y                                           
CONFIG_USB_EHCI_TT_NEWSCHED=y
```

to kernel resolved the problem.
Hope this helps you to avoid unnecessary debug flags and usless modules from your kernel.

Comment: Accepting this because it's probably closer than my answer. Wish I could test but the mouse died some months ago.

Answer (score 0):

After fiddling with the kernel's USB / HID settings, I finally got it working. I don't know /why/ it works, but for now I'm picking my battles.

I'm attaching a diff between the non-working config, and the working one in the hopes that it might help some lost soul in the future (more likely to be myself after I forget what the solution was :P).

The < signs indicate the non-working version, and the > signs indicate the working version. There are several flags in here that I suspect are the real culprits, like CONFIG_USB_HID, and several that are probably not related, like CONFIG_USB_DEBUG.

If anyone looking at this could enlighten me further, I would really appreciate that!

Anyway, here's the diff:

```
2943c2943
< CONFIG_USB_HID=m
---
> CONFIG_USB_HID=y
2955c2955
< CONFIG_USB_COMMON=m
---
> CONFIG_USB_COMMON=y
2957,2958c2957,2958
< CONFIG_USB=m
< # CONFIG_USB_DEBUG is not set
---
> CONFIG_USB=y
> CONFIG_USB_DEBUG=y
2966,2968c2966,2971
< # CONFIG_USB_OTG is not set
< # CONFIG_USB_MON is not set
< # CONFIG_USB_WUSB_CBAF is not set
---
> CONFIG_USB_OTG=y
> # CONFIG_USB_OTG_WHITELIST is not set
> # CONFIG_USB_OTG_BLACKLIST_HUB is not set
> CONFIG_USB_MON=y
> CONFIG_USB_WUSB_CBAF=y
> CONFIG_USB_WUSB_CBAF_DEBUG=y
2973,2986c2976,2988
< # CONFIG_USB_C67X00_HCD is not set
< CONFIG_USB_XHCI_HCD=m
< # CONFIG_USB_XHCI_HCD_DEBUGGING is not set
< CONFIG_USB_EHCI_HCD=m
< # CONFIG_USB_EHCI_ROOT_HUB_TT is not set
< # CONFIG_USB_EHCI_TT_NEWSCHED is not set
< CONFIG_USB_EHCI_PCI=m
< CONFIG_USB_EHCI_HCD_PLATFORM=m
< # CONFIG_USB_OXU210HP_HCD is not set
< CONFIG_USB_ISP116X_HCD=m
< # CONFIG_USB_ISP1760_HCD is not set
< # CONFIG_USB_ISP1362_HCD is not set
< CONFIG_USB_OHCI_HCD=m
< CONFIG_USB_OHCI_HCD_SSB=y
---
> CONFIG_USB_C67X00_HCD=y
> CONFIG_USB_XHCI_HCD=y
> CONFIG_USB_XHCI_HCD_DEBUGGING=y
> CONFIG_USB_EHCI_HCD=y
> CONFIG_USB_EHCI_ROOT_HUB_TT=y
> CONFIG_USB_EHCI_TT_NEWSCHED=y
> CONFIG_USB_EHCI_PCI=y
> CONFIG_USB_EHCI_HCD_PLATFORM=y
> CONFIG_USB_OXU210HP_HCD=y
> CONFIG_USB_ISP116X_HCD=y
> CONFIG_USB_ISP1760_HCD=y
> CONFIG_USB_ISP1362_HCD=y
> CONFIG_USB_OHCI_HCD=y
2991c2993
< CONFIG_USB_UHCI_HCD=m
---
> CONFIG_USB_UHCI_HCD=y
2993,2994c2995,2996
< CONFIG_USB_SL811_HCD=m
< # CONFIG_USB_SL811_HCD_ISO is not set
---
> CONFIG_USB_SL811_HCD=y
> CONFIG_USB_SL811_HCD_ISO=y
2996c2998
< CONFIG_USB_R8A66597_HCD=m
---
> CONFIG_USB_R8A66597_HCD=y
3002,3005c3004,3007
< CONFIG_USB_ACM=m
< CONFIG_USB_PRINTER=m
< # CONFIG_USB_WDM is not set
< # CONFIG_USB_TMC is not set
---
> CONFIG_USB_ACM=y
> CONFIG_USB_PRINTER=y
> CONFIG_USB_WDM=y
> CONFIG_USB_TMC=y
3015,3016c3017,3019
< # CONFIG_USB_STORAGE_DEBUG is not set
< # CONFIG_USB_STORAGE_REALTEK is not set
---
> CONFIG_USB_STORAGE_DEBUG=y
> CONFIG_USB_STORAGE_REALTEK=m
> CONFIG_REALTEK_AUTOPM=y
3042c3045,3046
< CONFIG_USB_SERIAL=m
---
> CONFIG_USB_SERIAL=y
> # CONFIG_USB_SERIAL_CONSOLE is not set
```